# Why do not work @Validated in spring boot 2.6.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
@Validated
public class ValueController {

@PostMapping(value = "/values")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createValues(@RequestParam @Min(10) int number) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(CREATED).body(number);
}
}
```

if i send post: 127.0.0.1:8080/api/values?number=5 return 5, but i want exception, what i need? java 11, spring boot 2.6.2

Comment: Remove `hibernate-validator`, remove `validation-api`... Fix any compilation issues and restart.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when `hibernate-validator` dependency is included in the classpath.

With the version of `spring-boot-starter-validation` specified above, you no longer need the `hibernate-validator`. Removing it should make it work as expected.

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation -> 2.6.7
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.7 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.62
|    \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.2.3.Final
|         +--- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2
|         +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final -> 3.4.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Add @Valid before @RequestParam as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> createValues(@Valid @RequestParam @Min(10) int number) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: You don't mention the number as a variable in your post mapping value. I think the problem may be caused by that. Try using '@GETMapping' instead of '@PostMapping' and see if the problem solves.

Comment: problem don't solves

Comment: Adding `@Valid` won't fix this as that will only work for `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` not for `@RequestParam` etc.